# Etsy V3 API Get Listing by SKU

Tags: c#, etsy

I am trying to build a C# library for the Etsy API. I only see Etsy 2.0 and 1.0 APIs available on nuGet.

1. How do I find a listing, based on SKU? I find no endpoint: https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference#operation/getListing
2. If no endpoint exists, do I need to pull all the listings, enumerate and match the SKU?

Comment: Have you tried calling the endpoint in postman?https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/listings/{listing_id}

Comment: I have only the SKU. I must obtain a listing ID without a SKU. Looking at V2, it appears I must pull all listings and filter by SKU: https://github.com/skuvault-integrations/etsyAccess/blob/master/src/EtsyAccess/Services/Items/EtsyItemsService.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no endpoint available (currently) which allows you to get a listing using its SKU, only using the internal Etsy ListId.

I'd recommend that you raise an issue on Etsy's API Github repo to request it as a new feature and who knows, they may build an endpoint for it.

https://github.com/etsy/open-api/issues